# Is 2 hours enough time to change terminals at Singapore?

Tags: short-connections, airport-terminals, sin

I have a layover of 2 hours at Singapore, within which I need to change from terminal 3 to terminal 1. The flights are with the same airline, purchased as a single ticket completely  Will I have any trouble?

Answer (score 7):

That's fine. One may take the [train](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changi_Airport_Skytrain) for the terminal transfer, which gives a nice view of the Jewel indoor fountain.

Comment: Even with the train transfer between terminals, one may end up having to walk quite the distance!

Comment: @Xi'anнівійні especially if you do a random walk, which people in your field commonly engage in.

Comment: When I crossed Changi two months ago, the random walk was mostly caused by my looking for the xiao long bao restaurant there!

Answer (score 3):

While Changi airport is quite large, this is perfectly doable.

The worst case if your plane arrives at A18 and the next one leaves from D49 (i.e. at opposite edges of the terminal) is about 45 minutes walk, but there are people movers to shorten this, and in the best case (B10 to C1) it’s less than 5 minutes.

You will exit directly from the gate into the transit/departures area, and will only go through security near the departure gate (with a checkpoint covering one to three gates). No passport control involved.

If your incoming flight is on time you should have no problem at all doing this, unless you have difficulty walking, in which case you should ask for assistance. Just don’t waste too much time in all the shops and activities on the way!

If your incoming flight is late and you miss your connection (it would probably need to be over an hour late), then since you are booked on a single ticket, it is the airline’s responsibility to rebook you on the next available flight and take care of you in the meantime. Depending on the next destination, that may involve a delay of a few hours or in the most extreme case the next day (they should pay for an hotel in that case).